# performing convolution or correlation will be same if the filter is symmetric in Digital Image Processing. Why?

Tags: image-processing, correlation, convolution

Convolution and correlation are in most cases different and produce different outputs. But when the filter used for convolution or correlation is symmetric, we get the same output for both. Why? What property makes the output the same for both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Wiki:

> Some features of convolution are similar to cross-correlation: for real-valued functions, of a continuous or discrete variable, it differs from cross-correlation only in that either f(x) or g(x) is reflected about the y-axis; thus it is a cross-correlation of f(x) and g(−x), or f(−x) and g(x).

If the g(x)==g(-x), i.e. the function is even (symmetric), then the correlation is equal to the convolution.